# Center bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am failing to recognize bootstrap navbar conventions, and Im unable to horizontally center the `a` tags' text in the middle of the navbar.  can't seem to find an example that matches this

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Values</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Safety</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cities</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is what I tried, to no avail.

```
 .navbar{
   text-align: center;
}

.navbar-header{
display: inline-block;
float: none;
 }
```

Comment: Enclose that in a `<div class='container'>....</div>`.

Comment: ...as opposed to `container-fluid` ?

Comment: or add another `container` tag?

Answer (score 0):

here's a jsfiddle for your request :
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4jgxnc4/)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: you didnt link that correctly.  im landing on this url

http://%20https//jsfiddle.net/o4jgxnc4/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float` and re-align the navbar links. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
      float: none !important;
      display: inline-block;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
       text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: where are you getting `.navbar-collapse` from?  it's neither in my code, nor in yours

Comment: The html I provided is a part of the standard bootstrap navbar markup which I assumed you were using too. The ul navbar-nav above is nested under a certain parent div right?? Just replace navbar-toggle with that parent div name and it should work

Answer (score -1):

Like this, enclose links in a list:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```